# Why custom icons do not appear correct on mobile phones?

Tags: android, iphone, jquery-mobile, icons, viewport

I've developed an app using `jQuery mobile` and `PhoneGap` tools. All of my icons are custom icons. When I checked on web browsers, all look fine but when I publish to mobile phones (both Android and iPhone), icons look weired.

[image]

The info icon with i looks fine, but the others (left, right arrows, nav-bar icons) looks wrong.

1. Does this have anything to do with icon resolution / viewport-meta
   tags ? How can I solve this issue?
2. How can I provide different resolutions of icons for platforms using PhoneGap.

Here I found a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8091427/jquery-mobile-custom-icons-on-buttons-look-strange-on-iphone?rq=1) but not solved as it seems.

Comment: For Android I know it uses multiple drawable folders. Each folder will be automatically accessed based on the resolution of the display. If you are only using the a image of one size that could be a cause to your problem.

Comment: I'm using PhoneGap therefore all my resources are inside assest/* directory, unlike native Android development where we'd put resources in res folder accoring resolutions, any thoughts on that?

Comment: See if [Targeting Screens from Web Apps](https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/targeting.html) helps

Comment: What format do you use for the images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is where you're running into problems, but it might be worth taking a look at this link: [Creating and using custom icons in jQuery](http://andymatthews.net/read/2011/02/13/Creating-and-using-custom-icons-in-jQuery-Mobile).

There should be two sizes depending on the screen resolution of the device, one at 18x18px and the other at 36x36. The .css tells the device which icon to serve up by using -webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:

```
.ui-icon-happy {
    -moz-border-radius: 9px 9px 9px 9px;
    background: url("../img/happy.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) !important;
}

@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
  .ui-icon-happy {
      -moz-border-radius: 9px 9px 9px 9px;
      background: url("../img/happy@2x.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) !important;
      background-size: 18px 18px;
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks, this is the correct answer, can somebody award the bounty now?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look to this page on the phonegap website:
http://build.phonegap.com/docs/config-xml

They explain a lot of points, the interesting part for you is in the chapter "Other Useful Elements" where they explain how to integrate icons for Android:

> We support ldpi, mdpi, hdpi, and xhdpi displays; the following will define icons for each specific screen type.

And the code example provided for every density:

```
<icon src="icons/android/ldpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="ldpi" />
<icon src="icons/android/mdpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="mdpi" />
<icon src="icons/android/hdpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="hdpi" />
<icon src="icons/android/xhdpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="xhdpi" />
```

You can have a try!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using a 9-patch image? http://iphonedevlog.wordpress.com/2013/07/02/creating-and-installing-a-splash-screen-for-android-using-eclipse-and-phonegap/

Answer (score 0):

I've also seen weird banding / stripes in a completely different context -- png files in a toolbar on wxwidgets (a cross-platform thick client framework).

The problem there was that some of my image files weren't completely square / weren't the dimensions that the toolbar framework expected. When they were vectorized and pulled in as a memory stream, they ended up looking kind of like what I'm seeing in your screen shot and on the related question.

It's a long shot, but it might be worth verifying that the dimensions for your icons match what is expected.